# php cURL didn't received data

Tags: php

I have a page `a.php` that uses cURL to post data to `b.php` page.
However, when the page header to `b.php`, I didn't receive any POST data.

Here is my code:

```
$data=array();
$data['firstname']='A';
$data['lastname']='B';

$post_str='';
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $post_str.=$key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';  
}

$post_str=substr($post_str, 0, -1);//Remove last & from loop

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/b.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
header('location:b.php');
```

**b.php page**

```
echo $_POST['firstname'];
```

Comment: The curl post, and your header redirect will count as 2 separate http requests, which means the echo won't output anything, because nothing was posted on the redirect. You could add an `error_log($_POST['firstname'])` and you should see the value in your error log for the curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this call:

```
header('location:b.php');
```

relocates to `b.php` **without** any `$_POST` data.

Comment: so how can i pass data to b page?

Comment: You could use GET: `header('location: b.php?foo=bar')`.

Comment: Im actually have a sign up page -> checking data page -> agreement page, in my checking data page have if statement. if all data correct it will post to agreement page

Comment: Better perhaps to use sessions. Let the posting be done by the users.

Comment: i use session before, yet will it cause more loading for server?

Comment: maybe i should add session destory after they click agree or disagree

Answer (score 0):

You have two php scripts, but they aren't really connected as far as the browser is concerned. The web, after all, was intended to be stateless.
Your a.php may very well be successfully posting to b.php.

But the `header('location:b.php');` line calls b.php without any parameters.

To make a.php a little more generic, I changed
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/b.php');`

to:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/b.php');`

b.php needs to record and then display results:

```
<?
// if called without POST data, dump the last POST,
// otherwise record the POST in a file

$filename = 'temp_data.txt';
if (count($_POST) == 0) {
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        // dump recorded results
        echo "<pre>\n";
        readfile($filename);
        echo "</pre>\n";
    } else {
        echo 'No file available.';
    }

} else {
// record results:
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, print_r($_POST, true));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

So open a.php, THEN open b.php in your browser.